# Pass variable in function js

Tags: javascript, function

I have code :

```
<td><input type="hidden" id="someText" name="someText" value="Hello World!">  </td>
<td><button onclick="test(document.getElementById('someText'))">Invoke Some</button></td>
```

I want to pass someText to my test() . But I get [object HTMLInputElement]. 
I must pass it in html no in

Comment: what do you need to send? complete the question

Answer (score 4):

You are passing the Element Object, you need to access its `value`

```
<td><button onclick="test(document.getElementById('someText').value)">Invoke Some</button></td>
```

Replaced

```
test(document.getElementById('someText'))
```

with

```
test(document.getElementById('someText').value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the id of the div to get the **value** in it and pass it to the function.

```
<input type="hidden" id="someText" name="someText" value="Hello World!">  </td>
<td>
    <button onclick="test(document.getElementById('id of your div').value)">Invoke Some</button>
</td>
```